# Spring Kafka requires non necessary avro

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, avro, spring-kafka

Good afternoon everyone,

I have a situation: I'm consuming a topic that has "N" event type. However, I only need to consume 2 events types from that topic.
The avros schemas define that they extends from "org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificRecordBase".
But once the consumer is started, it throws exceptions saying it couldn't find an event avro class that I don't need in the application.

```
The Listener class:

@KafkaListener(
    groupId = "${spring.kafka.consumer.group-id}",
    topicPartitions = {
        @TopicPartition(
            topic = "${spring.kafka.consumer.topic}",
            partitions = {"0", "1", "2"},
            partitionOffsets = {
                @PartitionOffset(partition = "*", initialOffset = "772000")
            })
    }
)
public class Event {

  private final Metric metric;

  @KafkaHandler
  public void handle(@Payload EventNameOne payload, final Acknowledgment acknowledgment) {
    try {
      System.out.println(" PAYLOAD EventNameOne " + EventNameOne );
    } catch (Exception genericException) {
      log.error("...");
    } finally {
      acknowledgment.acknowledge();
    }


  @KafkaHandler(isDefault = true)
  public void handleDefault(
      @Headers Map<String, SpecificRecord> sourceHeader,
      ConsumerRecord<String, SpecificRecord> payload,
      Acknowledgment ack
  ) { /* A NÃO PROCESSAR */ }
 }
```

Exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.DeserializationException: failed to 
deserialize; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error 
deserializing Avro message for id 8666;
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error deserializing Avro message for id 8666;
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Could not find class EventNameFive specified in writer's schema whilst finding reader's schema for a SpecificRecord.
```

Properties:

```
...
spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earliest
spring.kafka.consumer.properties.specific.avro.reader=true
spring.kafka.consumer.key-deserializer=org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.ErrorHandlingDeserializer
spring.kafka.consumer.value-deserializer=org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.ErrorHandlingDeserializer
spring.kafka.consumer.properties.spring.deserializer.key.delegate.class=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
spring.kafka.consumer.properties.spring.deserializer.value.delegate.class=...AvroDeserializer
spring.kafka.consumer.fetch-min-size=65536
spring.kafka.consumer.isolation.level=read_committed
spring.kafka.consumer.enable-auto-commit=false
spring.kafka.consumer.client-id=CLIENT_ID
spring.kafka.listener.poll-timeout=10000
spring.kafka.consumer.max.poll.interval.ms=150000
spring.kafka.consumer.max-poll-records=500
spring.kafka.consumer.ssl.protocol=SSL

#-------------
# ACK - MODE |
#-------------
spring.kafka.listener.ack-mode=MANUAL
spring.kafka.consumer.ack-mode=manual-immediate
```

What would be the setup or configuration needed to do this "filtering" or simply ignore and not deserialize the event I don't need?

Comment: Are you sure you want to be using `EventNameOne` if you're trying to deserialize other types (regardless of what's on the classpath)? If you really want to handle multiple types in the same way, you'll need to use GenericRecord

Comment: There's concept that maybe confused me. Whoever defined the avro schemas specified it as SpecificRecord, not GenericRecord. That way, I can't, for example, check and filter via "avro instance type" (That's the way I tried, if there's another way, please I'll be happy to hear it). Who is trying to deserialize all event types would it be the handleDefault method? Would just two @KafkaHandler for the events EventNameOne and EventNameTwo be sufficient without the default?

Comment: You cannot define a class as GeneticRecord, hence the name. But that doesn't matter because all SpecificRecords are also deserializable as GenericRecord and that's the only possible way (besides consuming as byte arrays) you'd be able to consume any Avro. I'm not familiar with Spring Kafka, however, but I doubt you can have multiple Kafka handler annotations for the same topic. Go ahead and try, though